# password reset option php is generating wrong code

Tags: php

i'm working on a passowrd reset but the issue i'm having is that when ever the password is about to get update for some reason it changes here is my code

```
>?php
if ($password == $confirmpassword)
    {
        echo "$password";
        echo "</br>";
        //has and secure the password

        $npassword = password_hash('$password', PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array('cost' => 10));
         echo "$npassword";

        // Update the user's password
            $query = $conn->prepare('UPDATE users SET password = :password WHERE email = :email');
            $query->bindParam(':password', $npassword);
            $query->bindParam(':email', $email);
            $query->execute();
            $conn = null;
        echo "Your password has been successfully reset.";
    }
    else
        echo "Your password's do not match.";
}


 ?>
```

example im trying to use demo123 as password when i echo $password i do get demo123, when i echo $npassword i get a code and when i manually do

```
>?php   $npassword = password_hash('demo123', PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array('cost' => 10));?>
```

i get another hash Now this has does work if i add it manually if i use the variable $password i get another code wrong by the way cause i cant login but if i do it manual and update it then demo123 works.

what am i doing wrong, I'm a newbie

Comment: Try `var_dump($password);` instead of echo and post the results, there's probably a white-space or some special character at the end.

Comment: Also: You don't need to encapsulate your variables in quotes if you want to use them (eg. `echo $password;` or `... = password_hash($password, ...)` would have been enough). Actually, this is your mistake, you're generating the hash of the string `$password` and not of `demo123`.

Comment: string(7) "demo123"      is all i get

Comment: spent hours on this and never noticed that, you right that's why it would've never work, thanks it works now

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use variables in strings you have to use double-quotes (`"`).
In your case though, since you're using variables exlusively and not adding anything to them, you can just remove your quotes:

```
$npassword = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array('cost' => 10));
```

Also, since `cost` already defaults to `10` you can just omit that aswell:

```
$npassword = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
```

Answer (score 0):

`password_hash` results are always different, you can't query mysql by generated hash, you need to get the user and do `password_verify ($password, $hash);` instead

where **$password** is 'demo123' and **$hash** is password column value from DB

Comment: i'm not following you